# VBIDEを参照した場合、.NET Framework以外に何か必要になりますか？

Tags: c#, .net

タイトルの件、Visual Studio2015のプロジェクトで参照にVBIDEというものを加えて開発していますが、このdllは.NET Framework標準で利用できるものと考えてよろしでしょうか？
(.NET Frameworkがインストールされていれば利用できますか？）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「何か必要になりますか？」ではなく、ライセンスや使用方法などを考慮・検討して使用するライブラリを選定するべきだと思うのですが…？

---

質問文では「VBIDE」と書かれていますが、実際のライブラリの正式名称は「Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3」と思われます。
.NETアプリケーションがCOM参照を行う場合、[`Tlbimp.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer)を用いてCOMタイプライブラリを元に同等のアセンブリを生成します。今回の場合ファイル名は`Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll`となっているはずです。更に[型情報の埋め込み](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ee317478(v%3Dvs.100))機能により、`Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll`の中で使用している型情報だけをピックアップしてアセンブリに埋め込むことができます（Visual Studio上で操作した場合、デフォルトで埋め込まれる設定となっているはずです）。
結果的に、.NET部分に関しては追加で必要となるモジュールはありません。

ただし、本体となるCOM側の「Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3」は別途必要です。